# Echoing to $(tty) in a backgrounded process

Tags: bash, tty, background-process

Why does this not print anything?

```bash
bash -c '(while echo "not printing" ; do sleep 1; done) > "$(tty)" & sleep 10'
```

Even though this, for example, does:

```bash
bash -c '(while echo "is printing" ; do sleep 1; done) > "$(tty)" && true'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take your first command, and run it in a temporary directory:

```
mkdir eg1    # Create temporary directory
cd eg1       # ...and change to it
ls           # No output (obviously, no files)

bash -c '(while echo "not printing" ; do sleep 1; done) > "$(tty)" & sleep 10'
```

But now take a look in the directory:

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima roaima 1040 Jun  6 23:05 not a tty
```

What has happened here is that the `tty` command reports the terminal device such as `/dev/pty0` when it's executed with a terminal attached, and the message `not a tty` otherwise. When it's run in the background (`&`) as a subshell (`( … )`) there is no terminal device, so output is redirected to what happens to be a file called `not a tty`.

Now in the second case everything is very similar except that the subshell is not being executed in the background:

```
bash -c '(while echo "is printing" ; do sleep 1; done) > "$(tty)" && true'
```

In this instance `tty` is running in the foreground and can return the device name of the current terminal, so you see the output on your screen.

Notice that the `&&` is a logical connector such that the second command will only run if the first returns a "successful" (0-valued) exit status. Do not confuse it with `&`, which instructs the preceding command to run independently in the background:

```
# Run the ( ... ) in the background concurrently with the foreground process
( sleep 1; echo background ) & echo foreground; wait

[1] 32301
foreground
background
[1]+  Done                    ( sleep 1; echo background )

# Run the ( ... ) and then if it's successful execute the next statement
( sleep 1; echo background ) && echo foreground; wait

background
foreground
```

Depending on what you want to achieve you might want to consider using `/dev/tty`, or even not redirecting the output at all.